# Assigning new values to points from its position?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

I want to classify a set of points as it is shown on the figure, from the upper part of the map (First point), to the lower part (last point). The question is that I want to be the FID=0 the first point in the figure, the FID=1, the second one,etc.

I read something about modifying the FID,but in ArcGIS I don't know how to do it. It classifies the points with apparently no order, and the FID= 0 is on the middle part of the figure. The points were calculated decomposing a vector line.

[image]

Comment: This is a quite simple numerical problem, but I think there is no tool in ArcGIS to do that. It can be done with Python Scipy module.

Comment: You cannot modify the FID of a shapefile.  Each value represents the record number (zero-based) in the file. You could populate a **new** shapefile is the desired order, but it would be better to add a "seqno" field which would retain order during subsequent processing.

Comment: @Vince thanks for replying. Ro,  are you suggesting to manually populate the order, and then add it as a new field in the attribute table? Do you know any way to do it automatically? It can be with GRASS GIS, if there is the option do to it...

Comment: This is a good candidate to minimum spanning tree algorithm. There's an extension on geometry by Patterson. It will connect pairs of points by lines. Dissolve them and if no multipart was created, convert resulting single line to vertices, they will be ordered

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure there are vector-only solutions, but if you convert the original line to raster where all values for the line = 1 and the rest = no data, you could run a *cost distance* from the start point which would increment along the line. Then using *extract values to points*, extract those values back to your points and sort on that field. You can use *Sort (data management)* to create a new feature class which obeys the sort.

Comment: A raster solution to this problem is going the long way around the lake to the next campsite.

Comment: If original line is available, it is enough to convert it to vertices and spatially join originals to them. The only thing left - sorting by vertices OID

Answer (score 0):

If you have the original  line feature, you could try this:

1. Turn the line into a route feature. Use the Create Route Feaute Tool.
2. Use the Feature Vertices To Points tool to generate your point layer.
3. Use the Add XY tool to add x,y,m attributes.
4. Sort by POINT_M
5. Continue with rest of your workflow.